# FilePut does not prepend the two length bytes when writing a string to a binary file from C#. FilePutObject throws exceptions on classes/structs

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, interop

I have a app that needs to be both read and write compatible with a VB6 binary file. I learned about the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem` class and I am trying to write out a structure to the file.

```
FileSystem.FileOpen(file, "test.bin", Microsoft.VisualBasic.OpenMode.Binary);

FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.intTest);
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.dateTest);
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.stringTest, StringIsFixedLength: false);
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.boolTest);
```

Everything writes correctly if I put each item individually except the string. When the VB6 app writes the string it prepends two length bytes, my code does not.

[In the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z07he9as.aspx) it says Binary mode removes the length bytes unless it is in a structure. Setting StringIsFixedLength to true should of done that, but it appears that Binary mode over rides that setting.

I try to use `FilePutObject` and try to pass in a struct or class (which is what the msdn says you need to do to get the bytes to show up) it throws the exception

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  Message=File I/O with type 'PatchFileStructure' is not valid.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FilePutObject(Int32 FileNumber, Object Value, Int64 RecordNumber)
       at SandboxConsole.Sandbox.Main(String[] args) in E:\Code\Sandbox Console\SandboxConsole\Program.cs:line 41
  InnerException:
```

---

Full code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace SandboxConsole
{
    static class Sandbox
    {
        public struct PatchFileStructure
        {
            public Int32 intTest { get; set; }
            public DateTime dateTest { get; set; }
            public string stringTest { get; set; }
            public bool boolTest { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            var patch = new PatchFileStructure()
            {
                intTest = 5,
                dateTest = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                stringTest = "Test Name",
                boolTest = true,
            };

            int file = FileSystem.FreeFile();

            FileSystem.Kill("test.bin");

            FileSystem.FileOpen(file, "test.bin", Microsoft.VisualBasic.OpenMode.Binary);

            FileSystem.FilePutObject(file, patch);

            //FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.intTest);
            //FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.dateTest);
            //FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.stringTest, StringIsFixedLength: false);
            //FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.boolTest);

            FileSystem.FileClose(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my two files I am comparing. Spaces are added to the c# version to illustrate the problem.

```
vb6 - 05 00 00 00 24 F6 1D 5B 21 A8 E1 40 09 00 54 65 73 74 20 4E 61 6D 65 FF FF
C#  - 05 00 00 00 24 F6 1D 5B 21 A8 E1 40       54 65 73 74 20 4E 61 6D 65 FF FF
```

If I try to read the vb6 file from the C# everything works fine except the string, which returns null.

Comment: Do you have problems while reading back your data?

Comment: @L.B Yes, If i try to read the VB6 file from C# it returns null for the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FilePutObject` seems to be a lot more verbose and write out more metadata than is needed, primarily for variants.
Have you tried just:

```
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch);
```

This uses the "ValueType" overload.

Comment: This does not work, I get the exception `Use 'FilePutObject' instead of 'FilePut' when using argument of type 'Object'.` if I use a class and it writes out a 0 byte file if I pass it a struct.

Comment: I tried every combination, of class and struct, and using FilePut and FilePutObject. The only thing that did not throw a execption was using FilePut with a `struct`, however it make the file 0 bytes long, when I got rid of the `{get; set;}` it works exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the length out explicitly before the string:

```
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.stringTest.Lenght.ToInt16);
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.stringTest, StringIsFixedLength: false);
```

Comment: This looks like the solution I have to do, I just wish I could figure out what I am doing wrong for the classes.

Comment: Is it a class or a struct? your code above only shows a struct.

Comment: I tried both, your other solution worked though when I removed the {get; set;} from the struct.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
FileSystem.FilePut(file, patch.stringTest, StringIsFixedLength: false);
```

The system isn't writing the length prefix because you're telling it the string is fixed length.

Comment: It will not put the length if it is true or false when the mode is Binary, it says on the MSDN it must be in a structure for it to display it, but when I try to pass a struct or class to file put object I get a exception.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Deanna's answer (use FilePut rather than FilePutObject) works.