# Read VB 6 binary file in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

I have a binary file written by VB6 application and now would like to use C# application to read the VB6 exported binary file. I have used the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll into my C# project.

However there are some data inconsistency in C# application but I have check it in VB.net and it works nicely as well. (I convert from VB6 to VB.net, then VB.net to C#)

[image]

The screenshot represents the result from reading binary file by using C# and VB.Net application.
VB.Net is my expected result and now my C# application was showing inconsistency result

Both are double values in C# and VB.NET, and based on my observation, the int, string values looks fine.

In C# I was using statement shown as below, BinaryDetails is struct and inside have few double variables

```
ValueType DetailsValueType = (ValueType)BinaryDetails;
FileSystem.FileOpen(FileNumber, FileName, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read);
FileSystem.FileGet(FileNumber, ref DetailsValueType);
```

I have change the data type in C# from double to float, still not my expected result:
[image]

Comment: I am lost :( IMHO, the question needs more clarity.. but not even sure what to suggest as improvement.. For starters, what are these screenshots to show?

Comment: the screenshot represents the result from reading binary file by using C# and VB.Net application. VB.Net is my expected result and now my C# application was showing inconsistency result

Comment: Why on earth are you casting to ValueType?

Comment: Is there anyway you can add to your question one record from the file?

Comment: You are saying you were successful on getting it to read in VB.NET, right? So just use an online VB.NET to C# converter to get it into C# code.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post what the struct you are writing to disk looks like. I guess that the issue is with VB and C# compiling the same struct to have different memory alignment. More information on how struct layouting can be influenced in C# can be found here: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290976/vb6-how-are-binary-files-encoded-using-put-statement and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043167/how-to-read-and-write-interoperable-strings-to-a-binary-file-between-net-and-vb

Answer (score 4):

You can reverse-engineer this kind of mishap with a little test program:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var value1 = 3.49563395756763E-310;
        var bytes1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(value1);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes1));
        var value2 = 101.325;
        var bytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(value2);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
CC-CC-CC-54-59-40-00-00
CD-CC-CC-CC-CC-54-59-40
```

Note how you are definitely on the right track, you are reading correct byte values from the file.  Those doubles have CC-54-59-40 in common.  It is just that you read the data *misaligned*.  You started reading too late, off by 2 bytes.

That's because your `BinaryDetails` is not an exact match with the data in the file.  Do keep in mind that you have to assume the file contains VB6 data types.  They are slightly different from C# types:

- VB6 file data is tightly packed, you need `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]`
- A VB6 Integer is a C# `short`
- A VB6 Long is a C# `int`
- A VB6 Boolean is a C# `short` with -1 = True, 0 = False;
- VB6 strings have a fixed width, you need to read them as byte[]

Ought to be enough to solve the problem.  And of course keep in mind that it is *very* simple to use a VB.NET assembly from a C# program.