# How to declare a fixed length string in vb.net without increasing the length during assignment

Tags: vb.net

I have a fixed length string variable:

```
<VBFixedString(10)>
Public myVar As String
```

When I assign the var to a value that has 11 chars the var changes length.

This is what I get:

```
  myvar = "1234567890ABCD" ' result = myvar being "1234567890ABCD"
```

What I want is myvar to be: "1234567890"

and then if it is less than 10 I would like

```
myvar = "12345" to be "12345     "
```

I can do this with PadLeft PadRight but was wondering if I can declare it as a fixed length and it would handle all that for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a fixed-length string in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305377/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-string-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and from the old school, LSET will do exactly what you're asking.

```
 myvar = lset("1234567890ABCD",10)
```

results in "1234567890", while

```
 myvar = lset("12345",10)
```

results in "12345_*_*_" - sorry, the editor trimmed the spaces after the 12345 replaced with underscores

see [MSDN entry for LSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7h739yk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I haven't looked yet, but if this exists in .net is there something like an RSET for right justifying?

Comment: The downside with this approach is it means using the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace. This means the call will be passed onto the VB runtime which provides an unnecessary dependency. The required functionality can easily be achieved with the a mixture of the String.SubString and String.PadLeft/String.PadRight methods.

Comment: magic-c0d3r yes, rset exists as well.

motosv - that's true, but the simplicity of a single call, in some cases, might outweigh the inclusion of the MS.VB namespace.  Most of my programs include it anyway so if it's there, why not use it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the `VBFixedString` attribute is *only recognised by certain file based methods* to help structure content written to/read from files. The compiler will not use that attribute for anything else, including to alter how a variable assignment is compiled.

Taken from MSDN:

> The VBFixedStringAttribute is informational and cannot be used to
>   convert a variable length string to a fixed string. The purpose of
>   this attribute is to modify how strings in structures and non-local
>   variables are used by methods or API calls that recognize the
>   VBFixedStringAttribute. Keep in mind that this attribute does not
>   change the actual length of the string itself.

The last sentence is the important bit:

> Keep in mind that this attribute does not change the actual length of the string itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbfixedstringattribute.aspx

EDIT 1:

A quick example on how to auto-padding a string based on a fixed length:

```
Function FixedLengthString(ByVal value As String, ByVal totalLength As Integer, ByVal padding As Char) As String
        Dim length = value.Length
        If (length > totalLength) Then Return value.Substring(0, totalLength)
        Return value.PadRight(totalLength, padding)
End Function
```

Here you can pass in a string and if the length of the string is greater than the specified total length you will get a string matching that length. Anything less and you'll get the string plus the padding character upto the specified total length.

This can be improved with error checking and maybe making the method an extension method so you don't have to pass "value".

Comment: So I have to do some extra coding to get it to be fixed length?

Comment: Yes. If you only want "x" amount of characters assigned, then you need to check if the length is greater than "x", then do a SubString otherwise pad the string variable you are assigning to "myvar".

Comment: I have added a quick example of using SubString/PadRight to get a fixed length string with/without padding.