# Declaring a string of a specific length

Tags: c, vb.net, vb.net-2010

From Visual Basic I need to call a function in a dynamic link library (DLL) which is implemented in C. The C function has the signature

```c
uint32_t F(char **str);
```

where *str* is an output parameter. The array `*str` is expected to be at least *n* characters long. On the Visual Basic side the function is declared as

```vb
<DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Shared Function F(ByRef str As String) As UInteger
End Function
```

How do I declare a string of length *n* in Visual Basic which is compatible with the formal parameter of the C function *F*?

Edit: The function call works as expected if I declare the actual parameter as for instance

```vb
Dim str As String = "          "
```

assuming *n* is 10. However, *n* is a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a fixed-length string in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305377/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: Is the DLL code under your control?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, but I would prefer not to change it.

Comment: Been there. Done that. Ended up using `BSTR`.

Comment: Could you preserve the existing functions in the DLL but add new, .NET friendly functions?

Comment: @IanAbbott The function call works (see edit) but I need a way to declare a string of length *n*.

Comment: The problem with the suggested similar question is that the simplest solution of using `Dim s as New String(ChrW(0), n)` comes really far down on the page.

Comment: You might be able to use the correct directives to get .NET to marshal correctly.  I'd recommend taking a close look at the documentation for `DllImport`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by TnTinMn in one of the comments, declare the actual argument like this:

```
Dim str As New String(ChrW(0), n)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `String` in VB is actually a `BSTR` on the C side, which is a struct in the Windows API.

On the C side, you use Windows functions like `SysAllocString` to manufacture a BSTR, and free the memory with a `SysReleaseString`.

You will not be able to interop (easily) with `uint32_t F(char **str);` between C and VB.

Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/string-manipulation-functions

Comment: The function call works as expected if I declare str as `Dim str As String = " ... "` (with *n* spaces), but I want to set the length dynamically (without constructing a string of *n* spaces).

Comment: This doesn't really address the question of how to interop with an existing function.  There is support for interop with native C strings.  It's also not correct - the native .NET string type is not a BSTR, that is only true of the VBA lineage.

Answer (score 1):

You can pad a string with n spaces.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim n As Integer = 10
    Dim paddedStr = s.PadRight(n)
    Debug.Print(paddedStr.Length.ToString) 'Prints 10
End Sub
```

Comment: A more direct route would be to use the [String(Char, Int32) constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_).  Something like: `Dim s as New String(ChrW(0), 10)`.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yes, this works like a charm. If you turn your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom, please just accept Mary's answer if this is the route you want to pursue. She is more than welcome to roll my comment into the answer. IMHO, while a declared length string works, the overall usage seems wrong when viewed from a .Net perspective and using a StringBuilder would be more typical.